# Error with Swagger v3 and Spring boot v3: Failed to load API definition

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, openapi

I am having a error in SpringBoot v 3.0.6 with swagger v3.0.0.

http://localhost:8007/doc/swagger-ui/index.html
Error URL:

Failed to load API definition.
Errors
Hide

Fetch error
response status is 500 /v3/api-docs

Log:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.Schema.getExampleSetFlag()'] with root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.Schema.getExampleSetFlag()'
    at io.swagger.v3.core.jackson.SchemaSerializer.serialize(SchemaSerializer.java:35) ~[swagger-core-jakarta-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at io.swagger.v3.core.jackson.SchemaSerializer.serialize(SchemaSerializer.java:13) ~[swagger-core-jakarta-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1572) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter._writeValueAndClose(ObjectWriter.java:1273) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValueAsString(ObjectWriter.java:1140) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at io.swagger.v3.core.util.Json.pretty(Json.java:24) ~[swagger-core-jakarta-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at io.swagger.v3.core.jackson.ModelResolver.clone(ModelResolver.java:937) ~[swagger-core-jakarta-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at io.swagger.v3.core.jackson.ModelResolver.resolve(ModelResolver.java:656) ~[swagger-core-jakarta-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at org.springdoc.core.converters.AdditionalModelsConverter.resolve(AdditionalModelsConverter.java:155) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
    at org.springdoc.core.converters.FileSupportConverter.resolve(FileSupportConverter.java:69) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
    at org.springdoc.core.converters.ResponseSupportConverter.resolve(ResponseSupportConverter.java:79) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
    at org.springdoc.core.converters.SchemaPropertyDeprecatingConverter.resolve(SchemaPropertyDeprecatingConverter.java:92) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
    at org.springdoc.core.converters.PolymorphicModelConverter.resolve(PolymorphicModelConverter.java:77) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
    at org.springdoc.core.converters.PageableOpenAPIConverter.resolve(PageableOpenAPIConverter.java:93) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
    at org.springdoc.core.converters.SortOpenAPIConverter.resolve(SortOpenAPIConverter.java:83) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
    at io.swagger.v3.core.converter.ModelConverterContextImpl.resolve(ModelConverterContextImpl.java:97) ~[swagger-core-jakarta-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at io.swagger.v3.core.converter.ModelConverters.resolveAsResolvedSchema(ModelConverters.java:110) ~[swagger-core-jakarta-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at org.springdoc.core.utils.SpringDocAnnotationsUtils.extractSchema(SpringDocAnnotationsUtils.java:122) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
    at org.springdoc.core.service.GenericParameterService.calculateSchema(GenericParameterService.java:373) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
    at org.springdoc.core.service.RequestBodyService.buildRequestBody(RequestBodyService.java:281) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
    at org.springdoc.core.service.RequestBodyService.calculateRequestBodyInfo(RequestBodyService.java:257) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
    at org.springdoc.core.service.AbstractRequestService.build(AbstractRequestService.java:343) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
    at org.springdoc.api.AbstractOpenApiResource.calculatePath(AbstractOpenApiResource.java:472) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
    at org.springdoc.api.AbstractOpenApiResource.calculatePath(AbstractOpenApiResource.java:652) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
    at org.springdoc.webmvc.api.OpenApiResource.lambda$calculatePath$11(OpenApiResource.java:219) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at org.springdoc.webmvc.api.OpenApiResource.calculatePath(OpenApiResource.java:200) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
    at org.springdoc.webmvc.api.OpenApiResource.lambda$getPaths$2(OpenApiResource.java:170) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at org.springdoc.webmvc.api.OpenApiResource.getPaths(OpenApiResource.java:149) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
    at org.springdoc.api.AbstractOpenApiResource.getOpenApi(AbstractOpenApiResource.java:334) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
    at org.springdoc.webmvc.api.OpenApiResource.openapiJson(OpenApiResource.java:124) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
    at org.springdoc.webmvc.api.OpenApiWebMvcResource.openapiJson(OpenApiWebMvcResource.java:111) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

My pom.xml

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.diceprojects</groupId>
    <artifactId>ApiExportExcelToEmail</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ApiExportExcelToEmail</name>
    <description>ApiExportExcelToEmail</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.5</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
                <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-commons</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
```

My Properties:

```
server.port=8007
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant-path-matcher

# SpringDoc configurations
springdoc.api-docs.enabled=true
springdoc.swagger-ui.enabled=true

springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/doc/swagger-ui.html
```

And My controller:

```
@CrossOrigin("*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/export")
public class ReportController {

        private final GetReportService service;
        private final EmailService emailService;


    public  ReportController(GetReportService service, EmailService emailService) {

        this.service = service;
        this.emailService = emailService;

    }

    //@RequestMapping(value = "/getReport", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @GetMapping("/getReport")
    public ResponseEntity<List<ReportDTO>> getReport(@RequestParam("date") RequestDataDTO requestData) {
        ParamFecha date = requestData.getDate();
        List<ReportDTO> fileContent = service.convertResultToFile(date.getDate());
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(fileContent);
    }

    //@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadCSV", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @GetMapping("/downloadCSV")
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> downloadCSV(@RequestParam("date") RequestDataDTO requestData) throws IOException {
        ParamFecha date = requestData.getDate();
        List<ReportDTO> fileContent = service.convertResultToFile(date.getDate());
        Resource fileResource = service.createCSVFile(fileContent);

        // Leer el contenido del archivo en un arreglo de bytes
        byte[] fileBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(fileResource.getInputStream());

        // Crear un objeto ByteArrayResource con el contenido del archivo
        ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(fileBytes);

        // Crear el encabezado de la respuesta
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
        headers.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", "reporte.csv");

        // Devolver el ResponseEntity con el archivo descargable
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .headers(headers)
                .contentLength(fileBytes.length)
                .body(resource);
    }

    //@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadExcel", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @GetMapping("/downloadExcel")
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> downloadExcel(@RequestParam("date") RequestDataDTO requestData) throws IOException {
        ParamFecha date = requestData.getDate();
        List<ReportDTO> fileContent = service.convertResultToFile(date.getDate());
        Resource fileResource = service.createExcelFile(fileContent);

        // Leer el contenido del archivo en un arreglo de bytes
        byte[] fileBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(fileResource.getInputStream());

        // Crear un objeto ByteArrayResource con el contenido del archivo
        ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(fileBytes);

        // Crear el encabezado de la respuesta
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
        headers.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", "reporte.xlsx");

        // Devolver el ResponseEntity con el archivo descargable
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .headers(headers)
                .contentLength(fileBytes.length)
                .body(resource);
    }

    //@RequestMapping(value = "/sendReportByEmail", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @PostMapping("/downloadExcel")
    public ResponseEntity<String> sendReportByEmail(@RequestBody(required = true) SendReportRequest request) {

        try {
            // Verificar si falta algún parámetro obligatorio
            if (request.getRecipientEmail() == null) {
                return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Error: 'recipientEmail' parameter is missing");
            }
            if (request.getSubject() == null) {
                return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Error: 'subject' parameter is missing");
            }
            if (request.getBody() == null) {
                return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Error: 'body' parameter is missing");
            }
            if (request.getDate() == null || request.getDate().getDate() == null) {
                return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Error: 'date' parameter is missing");
            }

            // Obtener el contenido del archivo Excel
            List<ReportDTO> fileContent = service.convertResultToFile(request.getDate().getDate());
            Resource excelFile = service.createExcelFile(fileContent);

            // Enviar el archivo Excel por correo electrónico
            try {
                emailService.sendEmail(request.getRecipientEmail(), request.getSubject(), request.getBody(), excelFile);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Error sending report");
            }

            return ResponseEntity.ok().body("Report sent successfully");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Error sending report");
        }
    }

    //Validador de resultados
    private ResponseEntity<Map<String,String>> validate(BindingResult result) {

        if (result.hasErrors()){

            Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();
            result.getFieldErrors().forEach(err -> errors.put(err.getField(), err.getDefaultMessage()));

            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(errors);

        }

        return null;

    }
```

---

But, I can't find the error :( help me please!!

I wanted to see my API documentation ;(

Comment: Could you try removing the springfox dependency? You only need the sprindoc dependency and I think that springfox is probably pulling in a different version of the io.swagger dependency than the one springdoc needs.

Comment: If I remove springfox dependency,I get other error: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.Schema.getExampleSetFlag()'] with root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.Schema.getExampleSetFlag()'
 at io.swagger.v3.core.jackson.SchemaSerializer.serialize(SchemaSerializer.java:35) ~[swagger-core-jakarta-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]

Comment: I solved it, when I deleted springfox swagger started dependency 3.0 and agree             <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.2</version>
            </dependency> // I think that openApi 2.0.3 is not compatible with swagger v3

Answer (score 0):

This is the dependency I used to be able to use SpringFox with Spring boot `3.2.2`

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```